# How to get around pagination URLs

Tags: templates, url, pagination

Does anyone have a neat solution to using pagination URLs? I would like to set up a simple structure like articles/article-entry with the listing and entry in one template. But once I include pagination in the listing I always end up putting the article-entry into a new template to avoid clashing with the pagination URL (ie articles/P2 etc). I then have articles/entries/article-entry or something equally as clunky.

I could use paginate_base to create a different URL for the paginated pages. But then I have duplicate templates for the listing. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Switchee](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) should be able to help you out there:

```
{exp:switchee variable="{segment_2}" parse="inward"}

  {case value=""}
    No value = landing page
  {/case}

  {case default="yes"}
    Default = anything which isn't landing or pagination (below).
  {/case}

  {case value="#^P(\d+)$#|''"}
    This is for paginated pages.
  {/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```